# "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" Error when running Selenium RC script

Tags: selenium, selenium2, java

First of all I have recorded the script in Selenium IDE, then exported into the junit4 (RC), then copied the junit4 (RC) code into Eclipse IDE. When I run the project with junit test, I found the error below. (I have included all the jars in eclipse.)

```
ERROR:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Charsets
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getOutputStreamWriter(HttpCommandProcessor.java:149)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getCommandResponseAsString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:176)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.executeCommandOnServlet(HttpCommandProcessor.java:118)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:101)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:275)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.start(HttpCommandProcessor.java:237)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:100)
    at com.example.tests.MyFirstSelenium.setUp(MyFirstSelenium.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I am really stuck at this point. Below is my exported code:

```
package com.example.tests;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyFirstSelenium extends SeleneseTestBase {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://50.116.76.60/");
        selenium.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/friend_circle/admin/login");
        selenium.type("id=username", "admin");
        selenium.type("id=pass", "admin");
        selenium.click("id=submit");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SQA, vinod. Selenium ships with lots of additional jar files.  Is is possible that your Eclipse project does not include them all?  `com/google/common/base/Charsets` is part of the guava jar.

Comment: Hi i Include all the external jars into my eclipse IDE ,But i did not include the guava.jar. Has guava.jar is useful to the run the Test case.

Answer (score 8):

I assume that you are not using stand-alone jar of selenium.
Can you download [Selenium Server Standalone jar](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar) 
and use it in eclipse. This is the only jar you need from selenium-java as it encompasses all required class files. You can remove other Selenium related jars from your eclipse.

Comment: HI tarun, Thanks for your replay, Now Its working for me.

Comment: @vinodguneja once an answer helps you, you can accept it as right answer